# preg_replace to trim everything except integers and : (colon)

Tags: php, regex

Would like to ask about how do I write a preg_replace in PHP to remove everything except Integers, ':' (the 1st colon encountered).

An example:

one (1) dog : four (4) cat sharing a drink costing USD0.40 or 40 cents.

to

1:4

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. I recommend you check out the [faq]. We are here to help you solve persistent problems with your code, not write it for you. When you post questions, it is **generally** a good idea to also post **what you tried already** and **why (and how) it didn't work as expected**

Comment: I don't think your example makes sense.

Comment: What about another colon in the same line, how should that be handled? e.g. `a1b:2:4c5` replaced to `1:2:45` or to `1:245`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are two examples:

```
    $input  = 'one (1) dog : four (4) cat sharing a drink costing USD0.40 or 40 cents.';
    $regex  = '~.*?(?P<first>\d+).*?:.*?(?P<second>\d+).*~s';
    $result = preg_replace($regex, '$1:$2', $input);

    echo $result;

    if (preg_match($regex, $input, $matches)) {
      $result = $matches['first'] .':'. $matches['second'];
    }
```

preg_replace() and preg_match() both will end up with same results.